# Java Lambda for Pagination scan for dynamodb

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

so I'm trying to scan a dynamodb table using lastkeyevaluated, limit and filterexpression.
I also want to take the returned lastevaluatedkey, filterexpression and limit from one dynamodb and add it to a new dynamodb table. This is my code right now

```
package dev.example;
 
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanRequest;
 import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanResult;
 
 import java.util.Map;
 
 public class ScanTable {
     static AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
     //static DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
     
     public static void scan()
     {
         Map<String, AttributeValue> lastKeyEvaluated = null;
         String status = "open";
         do {
             ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
                     .withTableName("tablename")
                     .withLimit(10)
                     .withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeyEvaluated)
                     .withFilterExpression(status);
 
             ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
             for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()){
                 System.out.println(item);
                
             }
             lastKeyEvaluated = result.getLastEvaluatedKey();
         } while (lastKeyEvaluated == null);
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         scan();
     }
 }
```

I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you need exactly?

Comment: 1. I need my scan to return lastkeyevaluated, limit and if the status is open or not and I want to add whatever I was returned to a new dynamodb table

Answer (score 0):

1. For Scanning the table take a look at [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html). This shows how to set the Limit, FilterExpression and how to paginate.
2. For adding the returned values, take a look at [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html#PutDocumentAPIJava) which show you how to do a PutItem request to save the values to a new table.